# vb.net com: get list by url

Tags: client-object-model

Is it possible to get a list by url? Something like this.

```
Dim list As SP.List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByURL("site")
```

If that isn't possible, is it possible to get the guId by using the page id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1. Get List by Url

The below solution demonstrates how to retrieve **List by its Url**, it consists of two steps:

- Get List Folder using `Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` by
  specifying List Url
- Get List by specifying `List id` from Folder `vti_listname` property

Code:

```
'1 step. Get List Folder
Dim listUrl As String = "/kb/Pages/"
Dim listFolder As Folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(listUrl)
ctx.Load(listFolder.Properties)
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Dim listId As Guid = New Guid(listFolder.Properties("vti_listname").ToString())
'2 step. Get List 
Dim list As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetById(listId)
ctx.Load(list)
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

> Note: SharePoint 2013/Online is supported only

### Option 2. Get List by Page Url

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve `List` by `Page Url`:

```
Dim pageFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/kb/Pages/Welcome.aspx")
Dim pageItem = pageFile.ListItemAllFields
Dim list = pageItem.ParentList
ctx.Load(list)
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: option 2 is working, THX!